# Faking rsnapshot initial backup

Tags: backup, rsnapshot

I'm currently using plain and flat `rsync` to backup my files, meaning I have no incremental backups.

A few days ago I became aware of the existence of `rsnapshot` and after looking at the man page I came to the conclusion that this is a great tool and I'd like to use it.

My 'problem' now is that I'd like to use my already existing backups as a base for the first `rsnapshot` backup.
After looking at the man page I'm thinking I should be able to move my existing backups to the `hourly.0` directory, `rsnapshot` would create upon the first `rsnapshot hourly` invocation.

Am I correct on this? Unfortunatly I don't have enough storage to make a backup of my backups for playing around.

Comment: Can't you experiment on a much reduced volume? Just set up a very small backup with rsync and try to get rsnapshot to use it as a base - this won't tell you if it really works, but you'll find out very fast if it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I guess, that is what I'm going to have to do

Comment: This should work, provided the directories under `hourly.0` have the same basic structure as those under `hourly.x`. Try it out with a subset and `-t`.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Post that as an answer, and I'll accept it

Comment: Finally tried it out and it works as a breeze. The only thing you have to pay attention to is, like Martin stated, that the directory structure in hourly.0 has to match the one hourly.1 would create.

Comment: Hi! Could you post this as answer and explain in detail, what you mean with "hourly.0 has to match hourly.1"? Why is this? Do I have to create hourly.1 too? Or do you just mean, that I have to create the directory `hourly.1/<instancename>/<original directories>`?

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation states](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync), you can make an incremental backup :

> In combination with the --backup option, this tells rsync to store all
>   backups in the specified directory on the receiving side. This can be
>   used for incremental backups. You can additionally specify a backup
>   suffix using the --suffix option (otherwise the files backed up in the
>   specified directory will keep their original filenames).

See [this example](http://rsync.samba.org/examples.html) provided on the official web site of rsync. It creates with a few lines a full backup and 7 day incremental. And since it's already the tool that you use, it should be easier to get already backup-ed files at the good place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I really want to use rsnapshot, because I like the idea of the way they use hardlinks, and because of its ease of use.

Comment: I am afraid that you'll need to delete your backup, then, before launching rsnapshot.